# How to store and retrieve multiple data using AsyncStorage. how to put multiple values in getItems. in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am new to react native. I have fetch data from an API. now I want to Push multiple data to server.
for example user name and application id. so how to store multiple values in getItems of Asynchstorage in react native. and If possible tell me how do I add Timestamp in this body to store real time in data base

here is my code. I want to send created By and application id

```
const { Place, date, nature, Distributor, DistributorCode, SalesCode } = this.state;
AsyncStorage.getItem('application_id').then((application_id) => {
 // AsyncStorage.multiGet(['application_id', 'created_by'], (application_id, first_name) => {
fetch('https://xyz.tech/Android_API_CI/uploaddata_merchant_retail_details', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
   // We convert the React state to JSON and send it as the POST body
   body: JSON.stringify([{created_by:<value>, application_id:<value> }])
 })
 .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
 .then(function(response) {
   console.log(response)
   return response.json();
 });
});
```

Comment: AsyncStorage can only store strings. As an example you can use `JSON.stringify({a: 'valueA'})` to convert your object into a string, and then `JSON.parse(myStringifiedObject)` to convert it back into an object. If you want to add a date you can just do `JSON.stringify({...myObject, date: new Date()})`

Comment: I want to send multiple value to server just tell me how can I do that my all values are in string

Comment: Since you wrap your data in an array I imagine it will say it's not a valid JSON. What happens if you use `body: JSON.stringify({created_by:<value>, application_id:<value> })` (i.e. without the square brackets)?